# Change UIImagePicker Buttons

Tags: swift

How do you edit the buttons on UIImagePicker's camera with custom buttons like this (With Swift) :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it possible, if you would design your custom view base on your needs and add to **UIImagePickerView as overlay view**.

Overlay view take place exactly on native camera view so it would help to hide default buttons/component of native camera view.

```
    var cameraUI = UIImagePickerController()
    cameraUI.delegate = delegate
    cameraUI.sourceType = .Camera;
    cameraUI.delegate = self;
    cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = getOverlayViewOnCamera()

    controller!.presentViewController(cameraUI, animated: ture, completion:nil)
```

Now, Our overlay view is on camera so all buttons action are on our hand, so we have to now call object methods of UIImagePickerViewController according to button press.

**Camera :**            takePicture()
**Video :**             startVideoCapture() / stopVideoCapture()
**Camera flash mode :** cameraFlashMode
**Camera Device :**     cameraDevice (Front, Rear)