# Swift: how to change the text of buttons in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uiimagepickercontroller

Could you please explain how to change the text of "Use Photo" and "Retake" buttons in image picker using **Swift**? I need to substitute them with an italian translation. I have found something in Objective-C but I don't know that language and I am not even sure it was for my case... Thank you

[image]

Comment: I am your same need at this time. If you have found a solution, would you share it with me?

Answer (score 1):

you need to make a **UIImagePickerView as overlay view**.

you can follow this solution 
[Change UIImagePicker Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956372/change-uiimagepicker-buttons)